# conditional type not inferred correctly

Tags: typescript

In this sample TypeScript code, I declare a function that has a [conditional return type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types).

```
/**
 * Do all elements of `a` appear in `b` and in the same order?
 */
declare function isSubarrayOf<T, U>(
    a: ReadonlyArray<T>,
    b: ReadonlyArray<U>
): T extends U ? boolean : false;
```

If array `a` might possibly be a subarray of array `b`, then type `T` *must* be assignable to type `U`, so the function returns a `boolean`. Contrapositively, if `T` does not extend `U`, there is *no way* `a` could possibly be a subarray of `b`, so the function must return `false`.

I try to get `false` in this test, but it’s still being inferred as `boolean`.

```
let a: number[] = [1, 2, 3]
let b: (string | number)[] = [1, 2, '3']

let test1: boolean = isSubarrayOf(a, b)
let test2: false = isSubarrayOf(b, a) // unexpected error!

/*
 * WAT?
 * `b` could never be a subarray of `a`,
 * since `string|number` is not assignable to `number`,
 * so the type of `test2` should be `false`.
 * however, the inferred type is boolean???
 */
```

So I did some more testing to make sure I wasn’t going crazy, but these tests all pass.

```
/*
 * testing: is `string|number` assignable to `number`?
 * if yes, `x` should be assignable to `y`.
 * if no, should get an error.
 */
let x: string | number = 'x'
let y: number = x // expected error

/*
 * testing: does `(string | number) extends number`?
 * if yes, `test3` should be `boolean`, assigned true.
 * if no, should be `false`, should get an error.
 */
let test3: (string | number) extends number ? boolean : false
    = true // expected error
```

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F**%0D%0A%20*%20Do%20all%20elements%20of%20%60a%60%20appear%20in%20%60b%60%20and%20in%20the%20same%20order%3F%0D%0A%20*%0D%0A%20*%20If%20%3CT%3E%20is%20assignable%20to%20%3CU%3E%2C%20it%20is%20possible%2C%20but%20not%20certain.%20%0D%0A%20*%0D%0A%20*%20If%20%3CT%3E%20is%20*not*%20assignable%20to%20%3CU%3E%2C%0D%0A%20*%20there%20is%20no%20way%20%60a%60%20could%20be%20a%20subarray%20of%20%60b%60%2C%0D%0A%20*%20so%20this%20will%20definitely%20return%20%60false%60.%0D%0A%20*%2F%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20isSubarrayOf%3CT%2C%20U%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20ReadonlyArray%3CT%3E%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20ReadonlyArray%3CU%3E%0D%0A)%3A%20T%20extends%20U%20%3F%20boolean%20%3A%20false%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20test()%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20a%3A%20number%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20b%3A%20(string%20%7C%20number)%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%20'3'%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20test1%3A%20boolean%20%3D%20isSubarrayOf(a%2C%20b)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20test2%3A%20false%20%3D%20isSubarrayOf(b%2C%20a)%20%2F%2F%20unexpected%20error!%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F*%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20WAT%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20%60b%60%20could%20never%20be%20a%20subarray%20of%20%60a%60%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20since%20%60string%7Cnumber%60%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20%60number%60%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20so%20the%20type%20of%20%60test2%60%20should%20be%20%60false%60.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20however%2C%20the%20inferred%20type%20is%20boolean%3F%3F%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%2F%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F*%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20testing%3A%20is%20%60string%7Cnumber%60%20assignable%20to%20%60number%60%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20if%20yes%2C%20%60x%60%20should%20be%20assignable%20to%20%60y%60.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20if%20no%2C%20should%20get%20an%20error.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%2F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20x%3A%20string%20%7C%20number%20%3D%20'x'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20y%3A%20number%20%3D%20x%20%2F%2F%20expected%20error%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F*%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20testing%3A%20does%20%60(string%20%7C%20number)%20extends%20number%60%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20if%20yes%2C%20%60test3%60%20should%20be%20%60boolean%60%2C%20assigned%20true.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20if%20no%2C%20should%20be%20%60false%60%2C%20should%20get%20an%20error.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%2F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20test3%3A%20(string%20%7C%20number)%20extends%20number%20%3F%20boolean%20%3A%20false%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3D%20true%20%2F%2F%20expected%20error%0D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you really want is:

```
declare function isSubarrayOf<T, U>(
    a: ReadonlyArray<T>,
    b: ReadonlyArray<U>
): [T] extends [U] ? boolean : false;
```

Notice the square brackets around `[T]` and `[U]`. This syntax tells TypeScript not to distribute over union types, which happens when using conditional types. See [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html).

With that change, your function will behave like this:

```
isSubarrayOf([1], [1])        // potentially true (the type is the same)
isSubarrayOf([1], ['1'])      // false (they have nothing in common)
isSubarrayOf(['1'], [1])      // false (they have nothing in common)

isSubarrayOf(['1'], [1, '1']) // potentially true (first is more narrow than the second)
isSubarrayOf(['1', 1], [1])   // false (first is wider)
```